# How can I open a Text file and find a specific strings value?

Tags: python, ini

I'm using Python 3.4 on a Win32 platform.  I want to open a file named somesettings.ini (just a text file) and search it until I find the value for a specific line.  Specifically, I only want to pull out the current setting for the Minimum Free Space= line (see contents of the somesettings.ini below) and save it in a string for use elsewhere in the code.  In the example of the ini file shown below, the string I want to end up with would be ***32000***.

Thanks in advance!

```
[Settings]
Idle Restart Time=300000
Minimum Free Space=32000
Max Record Time=1800
Deactive VR Timer=1800000
Use ERS=1
szaStorageDirectory=D:\
szaExportDirectory=Removable
szaConfigFile=C:\StreamsDefault.sdc
Enable LED=1
LED Port Address=3814
LED On Value=12
LED Off Value=4
LED Time Off=5900
LED Time On=100
Topmost Window=1
Grace Period=10000
Use Fast File Switching=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is for python 2.7:

```
f=open("somesettings.ini", "r")
for l in f.readlines():
    If "Minimum Free Space" in l:
        index=l.find('=')
        res=l[index+1:]
        break
f.close()
```

Comment: I am sorry about it. I wrote it on mobile giving proper spaces but still I cant format it properly. Will correct it tomorrow when I have access to my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) for this.

```
>>> import configparser
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read(r'somesettings.ini')
>>> config['Settings']['Minimum Free Space']
32000
```

You can access any of your settings in the `[Settings]` section this way.

At this point `32000` is a string. You will need to convert it to an `int`, if you expect an `int` later in the application:

```
>>> int(config['Settings']['Minimum Free Space'])
```